# Javascript lightbox component that works with arbitrary HTML

Tags: javascript, lightbox, popupwindow, lightwindow

Is there a Javascript component that allows me to simply pass it a string made up of arbitrary HTML (any HTML I wish to use) and will show that HTML in a lightbox?

I've been scouring the internet, searching for examples, but it seems like there simply isn't  any component capable of doing this.

Even LightWindow, which claims to be all-purpose, still requires me to attach it to an  tag with the href set to an element ID.

This isn't what I want. I want to be able to call a function and **pass in the HTML myself**.

(Another issue with LightWindow is that it requires scriptaculous as a dependency. The project already uses jQuery, and I'd rather not include two frameworks at once.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is great.  It relies on JQuery.

To use it with an html string, you would call it like this:

```
$.colorbox({html:'<p>Hello</p>'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) or [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

SLaks is correct.  You should definitly use [JQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  Here is an example of using the JQuery dialog as a modal, very similar to using lightbox.

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({modal: true});
```